# Handling more properties than what is needed

Tags: java, sql, groovy, properties

I'm trying to load a set of objects via a SQL call. The SQL query returns more properties than needed. Other than correcting the SQL query. How would I get groovy to ignore all of the extraneous Parameters upon declaration of Product?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class Product {
    Integer id;
    Integer type;
    String unique; 
}

def var = [];
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/[DB]", "user", "password","net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
sql.eachRow("select * from Products", { var << new Product(it.toRowResult()) } );
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: [other fields from the SQL result]
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Groovy behavior is to throw a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` whenever you try to set a value to a property that doesn't exist in the bean. I am not quite sure if you can change that behavior. However, you could write a helper method that filters out the properties that do not exist.

```
def filterResult(bean, row) {
    def filteredProps = [:]

    row.each { key, value ->
        if(bean.metaClass.properties.find { prop -> prop.name == key }) {
            filteredProps.put(key, value)  
        }
    } 

    filteredProps
}

def var = []

sql.eachRow("select * from Products", { 
    var << new Product(filterResult(Product, it.toRowResult())) 
})
```

Comment: That certainly makes sense. But I imagined that the properties were stored in a hash map coming in [rather than a direct 1 to 1 binding]. So it doesn't make sense to me that extra properties cause issues. Am I mistaken here? Groovy doesn't complain if you don't fulfill all of the properties, just if you have more than enough information.

Comment: By default Groovy indeed binds the map entries into properties in the class.  So extra keys will result in the groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException.  If you override Product(Map map) you can change this behavior.